# Save en MongoDB con SpringBoot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring, spring-boot

Como estan? Por favor alguien me podría ayudar con la siguiente duda, estoy haciendo una practica con una DB NoSQL (Mongo) con Spring Boot, pero cuando hago el save - Guardar un registro - Mongo por defecto le agrega el campo _id existe alguna forma de que no se cree ese campo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra pregunta, cuando creo la entidad marco con @Id el atributo que quiero que sea mi PK, pero cuando voy a hacer un findBy no esta buscando el parametro que yo quiero si no el _id.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente imagen es el repositorio que hace extend a MongoRepository:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando ejecuto el programa y desde Postman hago un get no me encuentra nada por que no esta haciendo el match correctamente, el siguiente es una imagen de como esta armando el Query, solo me funciona si en la entidad le quito la anotación @Id:

[image: Query cuando tiene el @Id la entidad]

Cuando le quito el @Id y ejecuto el programa lo hace correctamente, adjunto imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor repasar [ask] y [mcve]. El código, mensajes de error y advertencias deben ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y realizar los cambios pertinentes. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, no puedes evitar que se genere o cree el campo `_id` en MongoDB. Ten en cuenta que en MongoDB no existe el concepto de *PK*, es un concepto de Bases de Datos Relacionales. Cuando se usa el método `findById` se usa el campo `_id` por defecto, si deseas realizar la consulta sobre otro campo, debes usar un método diferente de `findById`, por ejemplo el método `find` o el método `findOne`. Saludos.

Comment: Como han ya explicado, primero debes de entender el concepto y forma de trabajo de cada tipo de base de datos, porque si estas con MongoDB y quieres trabajar como fi fuera una base de datos relacional terminaras con un mal diseño.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Respondiendo a si hay alguna forma de que no se genere, creo que no, ya que esto se genera de manera aleatoria de manera que hace que sea un unico registro.
El valor que se genera es de la clase ObjectId y tiene la característica de poder generarse con un valor único aunque se esté generando en servidores distintos.
ademas uno de los objetivos de emplear MongoDB es poder tener servidores distribuidos, la posibilidad de definir una clave primaria única y no tener que comunicarse entre los servidores se resuelve utilizando la clase ObjectId.

aqui hay una explicacion un poco mas extenso.
https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mongodbya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=18&codigo=18&inicio=0

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero recuerda agregar la parte esencial de los enlaces en tu publicación , revisa [answer]  y edita tu respuesta, saludos.